# Ada abstract type definitions

Tags: syntax, abstract, ada

I'm trying to define a number of abstract tagged types in an inheritance tree, and can't quite figure out the magical syntax combination.

I'd like to have...

```
type A is abstract tagged private;

type B is abstract new A with private; -- I can't get this one right...
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your code is syntactically correct, what error do you get?

Comment: plus, compiler version?

Comment: Thanks for confirming it was correct. I tried numerous combinations, and it seems I finally struck the correct version... when posting the question!

thanks...

Comment: @Dale you should read RM (reference manual) - syntax is well described in it.

Comment: Darkestkhan - I had looked though the LRM, I couldn't find an example of an abstract extension. Can you see where it is?

Comment: @Dale Syntax is described in chapter 7.3.